# Error when saving image file into Sql database

Tags: sql-server, image, linq, entity-framework, varbinarymax

I use Entity Framework and LINQ.

Simply, I want to take image file from fileupload control, and save it in a SQL Server database. But I get an error..

Table: `Images`

```
imageId int
imageData varbinary(max)
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[UploadImage]
(
    @img varbinary(max)
)
as
    insert into Images(imageData)
    values(@img)
```

C# code (after choosing file and clicking the button):

```
while (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
    byte[] imgByteArray = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length];
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imgByteArray, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);

    using (DummyDBEntities context=new DummyDBEntities())
    {
        context.UploadImage2(imgByteArray);
    }
}
```

Can you help me figuring out the problem?

Thank you

Comment: What exception are you getting, and which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: in model.context.cs file, 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: and in this line of code throws the exception:  return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("UploadImage2", imgParameter);

Comment: Look at the inner exception. What does that say?

Comment: I tryed try-catch blog for exception there was nothing.Then I looked from View Detail section and innerexception comes null.

Comment: Can you post your UploadImage2 function code?

Comment: public virtual int UploadImage2(byte[] img)
        {
            var imgParameter = img != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("img", img) :
                new ObjectParameter("img", typeof(byte[]));
    
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("UploadImage2", imgParameter);
        }

Comment: I checked again the innerexception. it says : "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'imageId'. Thats because I forgot to make Identity Specification in SQL table. Thank you so much for reminding me to look at the innerexception! and for your help! :)

Comment: No problem! Glad you figured it out.